# Mixing Ultegra or 105 left crankarm with Shimano Sora support

Tags: crankset, power

I'm interested in buying this power meter: https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/XCADEY-Bicycle-power-meter-Crank-power-meter-Bicycle-GPS-Computer-Garmin-Edge-Bryton-IGPSPORT-Support-ANT/32798182129.html. I have a Sora set in my road bike and I 'm wondering if a left crankarm dedicated for Ultegra or 105 would work with Sora crankset support of do I have to replace the whole set?

Answer (score 1):

Almost every Sora crankset from the past six years will be compatible with either a 105 or Ultegra non-driveside crankarm. To check if your crankset is compatible, you need to see if it's a hollowtech II model. These have the 24mm spindle attached to the driveside crankarm, while the non-driveside arm is then mounted using two bolts and a cap on the end of the spindle once the crankset has been put into the bike.

The Shimano Hollowtech II page [here](https://bike.shimano.com/en-AU/technologies/component/details/hollowtech-2.html) should help you identify whether your crankset is Hollowtech II. If it is, then you're safe to order that power meter, because it will fit just fine.